# angle between spacelike and timelike vector

Tags: special-relativity

What is the significance of the fact that the angle between a spacelike and a timelike vector has a real part of pi/2?

Comment: How are you defining "the angle between a spacelike and a timelike vector"?

Comment: The same way I defined it for triangles bounded by 3 invariant intervals. They may be calculated by the cosine law, or by the imaginary angle of rotation that a LT requires to turn from one leg into the other. One can also take the dot product of the two vectors. All these methods give the same answer, because there is only one answer consistent with the laws of trig, rotations, and the Pyth. Theorem. The triangle of the x and t axes and a moving worldline has acute angles of i phi and pi/2 - i phi, since they must be complementary. But the x-axis is spacelike, the other two sides timelike.

Comment: @murraydenofsky Taking the dot product of a space-like vector by a time-like one is fine, and so is using an imaginary time coordinate with the (++++) metric. But what if you use just real coordinates with a (-+++) ( or (+---) ) metric? How do you get your complex/imaginary angle then?  How do you separate a real part?

Comment: Without i, you get the same expression for the cosine of the angle, as the i is just there to enable you to get the same cosine using a Euclidean signature. The cosine expression has minus signs in it, and can be shown to be either greater than 1, or imaginary. In either case one gets a complex angle. Just square the cosine expression, and apply the inequality: the sum of squares of 2 variables is greater than twice the product of the variables.